# JW player will not play on IE10, 9 or earlier

Tags: internet-explorer, jwplayer

http://revenue.mt.gov/home/property/reappraisal.aspx#horizontalTab2 - this will take you to the page, inspect element - source is on page but I will include JW player snippet below.

What I'm trying to do doesn't work on IE, but works just fine on every other browser i have tried. I have to make it work on older IE9 because our company is still using IE10, 9, and so on. I am using an older version of foundation framework, as you can see with the first video I tried going back to primary: html5 and it actually shows up in IE, but if you hit the pause button it will refresh the page. I have been working on this for days on end.

Please help!

```
<div class="row" style="width: 1100px;">
<div class="four columns medium">
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>

<h3>Roadshow Part 01</h3>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
playlist: [{
    image: "http://revenue.mt.gov/Portals/9/Images/video-stills/Roadshow-01-still.jpg",
    sources: [{file: "rtmp://broadcast.mt.gov/revenue/mp4:Roadshow-Part-01.mp4"},
    {file: "http://broadcast.mt.gov:8080/revenue/streams/_definst_/Roadshow-Part-01.mp4"},
    {file: "http://broadcast.mt.gov:8080/revenue/streams/_definst_/Roadshow-Part-01.webm"}]
}],
width: "100%",
aspectratio: "16:9",
primary: "html5",

});



</script><noscript>
<object data="player.swf" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="360"><!--    Firefox uses the data attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below --><param name="movie" value="player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="streamer=rtmp://broadcast.mt.gov/revenue/mp4:Roadshow-Part-02.mp4type=rtmp&amp;image=http://revenue.mt.gov/Portals/9/Images/video-stills/Roadshow-01-still.jpg" /></object>
</noscript></div>

<div class="four columns medium">
<div class="flex-video" id="myElement2">Loading the player...</div>

<h3>Roadshow Part 02</h3>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement2").setup({
playlist: [{
    image: "http://revenue.mt.gov/Portals/9/Images/video-stills/Roadshow-02-still.jpg",
  sources: [{file: "rtmp://broadcast.mt.gov/revenue/mp4:Roadshow-Part-02.mp4"},
    {file: "http://broadcast.mt.gov:8080/revenue/streams/_definst_/Roadshow-Part-02.mp4"}]
}],
                                primary: "flash",
                                width: 360,
height: 240
});


</script><noscript>
<object width="360" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf">
    <!-- Firefox uses the data attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below -->
    <param name="movie" value="player.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="logo=mtgov.png&streamer=rtmp://broadcast.mt.gov/gov&file=mp4:MathSciencePSA.mp4&type=rtmp&image=http://broadcast.mt.gov/client/mathscipsa.jpg&plugins=captions-2&captions.back=true&captions.file=/client/demo-subtitles.srt" />
</object>
<p>If you disable Javascript you MUST have the Flash Player. Get it here etc.</p>
</noscript></div>

<div class="four columns medium">
<div class="flex-video" id="myElement3">Loading the player...</div>

<h3>Roadshow Part 03</h3>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement3").setup({
playlist: [{
    image: "http://revenue.mt.gov/Portals/9/Images/video-stills/Roadshow-03-still.jpg",
  sources: [{file: "rtmp://broadcast.mt.gov/revenue/mp4:Roadshow-Part-03.mp4"},
    {file: "http://broadcast.mt.gov:8080/revenue/streams/_definst_/Roadshow-Part-03.mp4"}]
}],
                                primary: "flash",
width: 360,
height: 240

});


</script><noscript>
<object width="360" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf">
    <!-- Firefox uses the data attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below -->
    <param name="movie" value="player.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="logo=mtgov.png&streamer=rtmp://broadcast.mt.gov/gov&file=mp4:MathSciencePSA.mp4&type=rtmp&image=http://broadcast.mt.gov/client/mathscipsa.jpg&plugins=captions-2&captions.back=true&captions.file=/client/demo-subtitles.srt" />
</object>
<p>If you disable Javascript you MUST have the Flash Player. Get it here etc.</p>
```

Comment: As a first step, update to JW Player 6.10. No sense trying to debug a problem with 6.3, which is obsolete.

Comment: Indeed, update to the latest.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that and see if it provides a fix

Comment: updating the player fixed all my issues, pretty obvious now that i think about it. thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: The only thing I cannot do now is expand the video in IE9, but they work now so i guess i can live with it...

Comment: Your last line of your setup code has a comma, I would remove that.

Comment: Thanks Ethan for all the help. I actually did not set a primary after looking at some other instances of JW player out there on the web. Working on all browsers now, except on my iPhone 4s Safari browser, but it does not have the updated iOS.

Comment: What version of iOS is on there?

Comment: iOS 7.1.2 is the version